# RIA Services versus WCF Services

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I'm rewriting an LOB application whose architecture is like this:

> Silverlight && Windows Mobile -> WCF
>   -> Entity Framework -> Database.

The mobile app was supposed to be able to do certain things as the silverlight app. What benefits would I get from using RIA Services here? Whats the advantage and disadvantage of RIA Services over WCF?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

.NET RIA Services was created for Silverlight that runs in the browser. Silverlight is running a special version of the the .NET framework and in an N-tier application Silverlight is unable to share assemblies with the server side. By employing some **clever code generation** .NET RIA Services makes this gap almost invisible to the developer. Classes similar to the domain classes are code generated on the client side, and ways to move objects back and forth between client and server are also made available.

You will probably be able to call into a .NET RIA Service from Windows Mobile, but I don't think it will particular easy and currently you may in fact have to reverse engineer what's sent on the wire (JSON is used). WCF on the other has a much more broad scope, but doesn't support Silverlight development in the same way that .NET RIA Services does.

If you are writing a Silverlight only N-tier application .NET RIA Services are very powerful. If however Silverlight is only one of several clients WCF is probably a better choice.

Please note the .NET RIA Services hasn't been released yet, but a preview is available for download.

Comment: would an architecture like this work well?

1) silverlight -> RIA Services -> WCF -> Entity Framework
2) mobile app -> WCF -> Entity Framework

Comment: Could someone with editing permission change this answer to reflect the current state of RIA (it is now available). Picky issue, I know, but the best thing about StackOverflow is being able to read old answers that are still relevant :)

Answer (score 3):

WCF RIA Services introduces several solutions for challenges you run into when using WCF from Silverlight. For instance, asynchronous loading of queries using the `EntityQuery<T>` is much easier than the Begin..End solution offered by WCF. Also, RIA provides integrated change tracking from your client that allow to submit or reject multiple changes as one change set. RIA will bundle all these changes into one request, but from your Domain Service it behaves as it were individual calls. As a long time WCF developer I can tell you that that is a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

Ria services are created just to be used with Silverlight. They are substantially a standard "package" ready to be used by Silverlight. The advantage is that you have a lot of services without need to write code i.e.:

1. Support for data annotations
2. Support for membership provider and login
3. Support for transferring to silverlight server side generated exceptions. There is a difficulty in silverlight that make difficultthe normal error transfer of exception through FaultContract. The point is that the browser is not able to handle all error codes. Ria services solve this with a trick

All things done by Ria can be done with WCF and with other available software and in particular with Wcf data services. For instance for data annotations I found [this library](http://validationtoolkit.codeplex.com/) that do a better job than Ria services, support for membership just require activating the already existing membership endpoint of a WCF service, and finally the exception problem is easily resolved by writing a WCF behaviour. Code is available  here:http://www.silverlightshow.net/Storage/10Tips.zip
The point is that with Ria Service you have all this in a mouse click!. On the other side Ria Services are really difficult to customize...so if you don't like the standard solution they offer you simply can't use them

Comment: You can use the RIA services as plain WCF services, and also as OData and JSON endpoints

Answer (score 0):

RIA Services is built on top of WCF.  With the PDC release, this will be much more evident.  RIA Services simplifies the client-side programming model so that it matches very closely with your server-side DomainService and entities.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless to the answer:

> RIA Services is built on top of WCF.
>   With the PDC release, this will be
>   much more evident. RIA Services
>   simplifies the client-side programming
>   model so that it matches very closely
>   with your server-side DomainService
>   and entities.

For me (and I guess that for the topic author) it is not clear what RIA services provide also besides access to the DomainService (which is same thing provided by WCF)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Until there is a formal release of WCF RIA Services, I don't think there is a definitive answer to this question. As of the current Beta (for VS 2008, SL 3), RIA Services does not hide the asynchronous nature of service calls; you still need to provide a callback method. Also, RIA Services does not currently support user-defined classes (or collections of user-defined classes) as either parameters or return values on RIA service calls. I'm also running into trouble providing non-editable entity classes through RIA Services. (The error says the entity collection isn't editable. Yeah, that is actually what I want....)

At this point, I need to fall back and take another look at making plain old WCF work. That's not so simple, given the size of the application we're developing, but it seems to be the workable solution until MS fixes some of the current problems with RIA Services.

Answer (score -6):

.NET RIA Services had been named as WCF RIA Services in PDC which was held in November 2009. Since it is built on top of WCF, hence the name **WCF RIA Services**.

You'll need to use WCF RIA Services for building N tier application involving database(or any information that needs to be carried along the tiers).

Comment: You do not **need** to use WCF RIA Services to build an N-tier application. Plain old WCF works, and there is also the option of WCF Data Services. Choosing between them is somewhat harder.

Comment: Seconded - RIA is ONE way to build an N-tier application with Silverlight.